# Eclipse & regular expression that matches word X, excluding some longer words, which include X

Tags: regex, eclipse

As an example: I would like to use Eclipse's File Search to count occurrences of `be` (case insensitive), but not count occurences of `believed`, `babel`, `wannabe` and `become`. Let's say that we have example part of "code":

```
// Belfast is believed to become a part of the world where 
// people use word "be" most often; wannabe, babel?
```

I would like Eclipse to count, that above part of the "code" contains 2 matches (in `Belfast` and `"be"`). To sum up, I am looking for a regex, which:

- match all words containing be (case insensitive),

and simultaneously:

- does not match explicite word `become`
- does not match explicite word `babel`
- does not match explicite word `believed`
- does not match explicite word `wannabe`

Could you tell me, how can I reach that?

EDIT: 
I have edited the question body, beacuse the example which I have provided previously didn't completly match question's title. Moreover, I have provided bulleted list with explicited rules.

Comment: Why match Belfast and not believed? You'll need to give us some kind of set of rules; currently it seems arbitrary

Comment: Haven't I already done that? 
* match all words containing `be` (case insensitive)
and simultaneously:
* does not match explicite word `believed`
* does not match explicite word `become`

Comment: Question EDITED at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: `(?i)\b(\w*be(?!lieved|come)\w*)\b`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/79VEzr/1

Explanation:

- `(?i)` - flag to enable case insensitivity
- `\b` - Match a word boundary (on both ends of expression to match an individual word)
- `(\w*be(?!lieved|come)\w*)` - Capture the word

  - `\w*` - Match any sequence of word characters
  - `be` - Match `be` literally
  - `(?!lieved|come)` - Negative lookahead to ensure that `be` isn't followed by `lieved` or `come` (removes believed and become from results)
  - `\w*` - Match more word characters after `be`
- `\b` - Match ending word boundary

Comment: If I would like to reproduce this answer to similiar case: matching all `ska`'s and ommitting `Polska`'s, should the following regex work correctly?
`(?i)\b(\w*(?!Pol)ska\w*)\b`?

Comment: @Czarek Close, but make it a negative lookbehind (change `?!` to `?<!`)

Comment: thank you for your contribution in the topic. Could you, please, take a look at the question after edition?